# Boost C++ struct in shared memory via function

Tags: c++, memory, boost, struct

I'm currently working with the Boost library to create a simple IPC.
I decided to outsource the creation of the shared_memory_object and the assignment of the structure into a function.
This is my function connect:

```
shared_data* connect(char *name){
    //open or create shared memory object
        shared_memory_object shm_obj(open_or_create, name, read_write);
        offset_t size;
        shm_obj.get_size(size);

        shared_data * data;

        //newly created
        if(size == 0){

            //set size
            shm_obj.truncate(sizeof(data));
            //map region to process
            mapped_region region(shm_obj, read_write);
            //get adress from region
            void * addr = region.get_address();
            //save structure to memory
            data = new (addr) shared_data;

            return static_cast<shared_data *>(addr);
            //or return data;
        }
```

It is called by:

```
shared_data * data = connect("shared_memory");
```

in the main function.

But as soon as the program leaves the function through the return statement my debugger shows, that all the values in the struct are no longer accessible. (unable to read memory)

The memory adress is correct and my calling line also receives this memory adress, but as soon as any other function wants to work with the variable data, it throws an access violation error.

I have absolutely no clue on how to solve this. I have already tried creating my object anywhere and then moving it to the wanted adress.

It would be great if you guys could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of your `shared_memory_object` ends as soon as the function scopes exits, so yes, you can't refer to the shared memory object anymore.

Keep the `shared_memory_object` in a location where the lifetime extends beyond the end of the function.

The usual approach is class members. You could make the function a member of the same class and keep the object instance around.